# Bind built-in Angular directive to method in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a custom directive that needs to watch for a `mousemove` event on the element on which it is defined. Is it possible to use `ng-mousemove` in this case, but have the function passed to `ng-mousemove` refer to a method on my custom directive's scope. For example:

**HTML**

```
<div my-directive ng-mousemove="go()"></div>
```

**Custom directive:**

```
...
scope: true,
link: function(){
  $scope.go = function () { ... };
}
```

I realize I can create the event listener within my directive to watch for a `mousemove` event, but that seems to go against the standard Angular approach.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate

Comment: try adding: scope: {
      ngMousemove: '&'
    }  
instead of scope:True

Comment: @DoronSinai But that would require me to define a `go()` method on my controller's scope, correct? I want to keep the functionality totally encapsulated within the directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying on arbitrary function from directive's scope doesn't look like 'totally encapsulated', more like the opposite of it. And btw, you can't do that anyway.

Standard Angular approach is something like this

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    scope: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude ng-mousemove="go()"></div>',
    link: function (scope){
      scope.go = function () { ... };
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: What if my directive is simply called via an attribute, and does not contain a template of its own?

Comment: Using extra wrappers isn't considered something bad in angular. You can add `replace: true` to eliminate another one and pass other attributes (e.g. 'class') from my-directive to the template. There's nothing un-angular in mousemove listener either, that's what ng-mousemove [essentially does](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.3/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L62).

Comment: Ok, I'll just add the mouseover listener inside the link function. Thanks!